# Google Sheets: Formula to Sum all the Cell Values Across Multiple Columns Associated with Max Date in Date Column

Tags: google-sheets, formula, sumifs, maxdate

I have a Google Sheet that is connected to BigQuery so the table automatically generates new rows of data every week.  I have a pivot table output that looks like below:

[image]

I want to write Google Sheet formula so that it searches through the date column, finds the max date, and then sums the values in col1, col2, and col3 associated with max date.  This sum populates inside a different cell in the same Google Sheet.

The dates will not always be in chronological order and new dates will get automatically refreshed into my table via BigQuery which is why I want to find a formula to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=sum(filter(B:D,A:A=max(A:A)))
```

[image]